# OpenServer phpmyadmin warning when xdebug.scream = 1

Tags: phpmyadmin, xdebug

**I am having this warning when I enable zend_extension, but I dont know which setting is causing this warning**

[image: PHPMYADMIN warning]

I am having this warning when I enable zend_extension, but I dont know which setting is causing this warning

> Here is my xdebug settings in php.ini

```
    [Xdebug]
zend_extension="%sprogdir%/modules/php/%phpdriver%/ext/php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.auto_trace = 0
xdebug.collect_includes = 1
xdebug.collect_params = 6
;xdebug.collect_return = 1
;xdebug.collect_assignments = 1
xdebug.collect_vars = 1
xdebug.dump.REQUEST = *
xdebug.dump.SESSION = *
xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
;xdebug.dump.COOKIE =
;xdebug.dump.FILES = *
;xdebug.dump.GET = *
;xdebug.dump.POST = *
xdebug.dump_globals = 1
xdebug.dump_once = 1
xdebug.dump_undefined = 1
xdebug.extended_info = 1
;xdebug.file_link_format = ""
;xdebug.idekey = ""
;xdebug.manual_url = "http://www.php.net"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 256
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1
;xdebug.profiler_append = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug/"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%H%R"
;xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
;xdebug.remote_log = "none"
;xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9009
xdebug.scream = 1
;xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
;xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
;xdebug.show_mem_delta = 1
;xdebug.trace_format = 1
;xdebug.trace_options = 1
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug/"
;xdebug.trace_output_name = "trace.%H%R"
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
;xdebug.var_display_max_data = 1024
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 16
;xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 3600
```

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: @MarcDelisle phpMyAdmin 4.7.7

Comment: This is an outdated version, the current one is 4.8.3.